# Why Mass Indexer is unable to generate indexes for multiple entities?

Tags: spring, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Lucene search for fetching the records from the Database.Here is my code snippet :

```
   fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

It is working fine but it is generating indexes for the entire database.I thought it's not recommended way of indexing to entire Database.After doing some search in google I found `MassIndexer` is the solution in the official doc.Here is my snippet :

```
fullTextSession.createIndexer(A.class,B.class).batchSizeToLoadObjects(25).cacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL)
.threadsToLoadObjects(5).typesToIndexInParallel(20).startAndWait();
```

Here I am able to fetch the records but, if I am passing some more entities like `C.class` and `D.class` along with `A.class` and `B.class` it is unable to create index for all the entities.Instead of all it is creating indexes for only 2 entities which tends unable to fetch some records.So, please recommend me some suggestions to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let me clarify some things.

The following code:

```
   fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

Isn't goint to rebuild the index of the whole database, but is going to rebuild the index of all known indexed entities.
Of course if you're indexing all your entities then that implies it's going to reindex all your database but generally you should flag as `@Indexed` only the entities which you need indexed.

Actually resitricting the types such as

```
fullTextSession.createIndexer(A.class,B.class) [..]
```

is a good idea and should work.

**Polymorhipsm**

If classes `C` and `D` are subclasses of types `A` and/or `B` then there is no need to list them explicitly. Asking to index any type will also index all its subtypes.

You mention "it is unable". Do you have any errors? Any warning being logged at all?

Comment: Tq for the reply :).No warning and errors is displaying.When I am adding more entities explicitly to the createIndexer(A.class,B.class,C.class,D.class) it is not generating any output.Simple it giving 0 records found.But If i am doing same thing without passing any entities with createIndexer() it is giving expected output.By the way A,B,C,D are parent entities no relation between them.And more thing what is the importance of include paths does will improve the performance??

Comment: Sorry I've never seen anyone report  problem like that. Could you clarify which version you're using and ideally create a test able to reproduce this problem? You can create one in github, this is a good starting point: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates Alternatively open a JIRA and attach a project to it.

Comment: @Sanne.Problem is resolved.I haven't done any thing in the mass indexer.I simply changed my associations as bi-directional i.e added@ContainedIn on other side of my relationship.And in my case I am not saving parent entity every time, I am saving its associated childs in most of the cases.I thought that index is not getting updated.Am I correct is this is the problem?

Comment: @Sanne.After doing that I am able to get my records.But if I am doing insertion,deletion or updation with OneToMany and ManyToMany.It is not getting update the  newly created record index.Finally I haven't found where is the problem.For that I did one thing.I created index manually for that record.
Like Object obj= fullTextSession.get( A.class, id);
fullTextSession.index(obj);                                                                    
Now I am getting records.
Suppose I am doing index manually along with MassIndexer is their any impact on performance??

Comment: lucene.version=4.10.4
hibernate.version=4.3.11.Final